# Theorem without bold

Tags: environments, theorems, bold

I would like to state claims so that they are numbered and in italics, but with no bold.

I can do a separate:

```
\newtheorem*{claim1}{\textnormal{\textit{Claim 1}}}
```

for each number.  But still the period at the end comes out in bold.  How can I fix that?

Comment: what document class and theorem package are you using?

Comment: amsthm ########

Comment: the `amsthm` documentation tells how to define your own `\newtheoremstykle`.

Comment: Package `thmtools` makes it easy and cooperates well with `amsthm`.

Answer (score 7):

Just create your own `\theoremstyle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\newtheoremstyle{claim}% name
  {\topsep}% space above
  {\topsep}% space below
  {}% body font
  {}% indent amount
  {\itshape}% theorem head font
  {}% punctuation after theorem head
  {.5em}% space after theorem head
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}% theorem head spec
\theoremstyle{claim}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Name]
A named theorem
\end{theorem}

% ---

\begin{definition}
A description
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[Name]
A named definition
\end{definition}

% ---

\begin{claim}
A claim
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}[Name]
A named claim
\end{claim}

\end{document}
```

Defining your own styles are covered in the [`amsthm`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) (section **4.3 New theorem styles**, p 9).